# Spring Data JPA + Eclipselink + Autowiring

Tags: eclipselink, autowired, spring-data-jpa

I have this little project that works with Hibernate + Spring JPA and I'm just trying to change Hibernate to EclipseLink. When I do that, my jUnit test case simply can't autowire the very same repository that works with Hibernate. I can't figure out what is wrong...

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceEclipseLink" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.test.repositories"></jpa:repositories>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceHibernate"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="persistenceEclipseLink"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.test.entities.Post</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

This will result in:

```
ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2c5af885] to prepare test instance [com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest@871fa83] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.example.test.repositories.PostRepository com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected [ManagedType] for the key class [class com.example.test.entities.Post].
```

If I simply change my entityManagerFactory to the bellow, everything works (using Hibernate):

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceHibernate" />
</bean>
```

Can anyone catch what am I doing wrong on the EclipseLink configuration?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here's my jUnit test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:META-INF/application-context.xml")
public class PostRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
PostRepository repository;

@Test
public void test() {
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setPostTitle("title");

    repository.save(post);
}
```

}

**EDIT**

Full stack trace:

```
3601 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager  - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6077e77a] to prepare test instance [com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest@2d2e3a2c]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.example.test.repositories.PostRepository com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected [ManagedType] for the key class [class com.example.test.entities.Post].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.example.test.repositories.PostRepository com.example.test.PostRepositoryTest.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected [ManagedType] for the key class [class com.example.test.entities.Post].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected [ManagedType] for the key class [class com.example.test.entities.Post].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected [ManagedType] for the key class [class com.example.test.entities.Post].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:424)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 36 more
```

Post.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POST")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    Integer postId;
    @Column(name="TITLE")
    String postTitle;

    (...getters and setters...)
```

}

PostRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.example.test.entities.Post;

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please include the full exception stack trace, (also the mappings for the Post class)

To use the same properties as you have in Hibernate,

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
```

in EclipseLink this would be,

```
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL" />
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="fine" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The configuration of EclipseLink seems to be working. As I run the code I also had "tail -f" on the MySQL log file and the schema is created, etc... The problem is when I @Autowired the repository... Spring can't handle it if it's linked to the EclipseLink datasource. That's what I can't figure out.